# Vue 2 animation issue on hover

Tags: javascript, vue.js, animation, vuejs2

I have two pictures, when hovering over the first picture, a certain component is displayed and the second picture works in a similar way, which displays another component, my problems began when I decided to apply animation when hovering over the picture, that is, I wanted to make it appear a certain component with animation, but the problem is that the animation works only for the first component, and for the second component, not only the animation does not work, it is also not displayed, you can see [my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue2-hover-animation-ycnrt) in the **sandbox**

If you looked at my code, you might have noticed that I display components using `v-for`, but when I tried to display components manually (that is, without a loop), everything worked fine for me, that is, like this

```
<div style="margin-top: 200px;">
  <slide-y-up-transition>
    <RedExperience v-show="img1" key="img1"/>
  </slide-y-up-transition>
  <slide-y-up-transition>
    <OrangeExperience v-show="img2" key="img2"/>
  </slide-y-up-transition>
  <slide-y-up-transition>
    <GreenExperience v-show="img4" key="img4"/>
  </slide-y-up-transition>
</div>
```

**Here is my code from sandbox**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center">
      <div v-bind:key="index" v-for="(girl, index) in girls">
        <img
          style="width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 5px"
          @mouseover="mouseOver(girl)"
          @mouseout="mouseout(girl)"
          v-bind:src="girl.imgSrc"
          alt="Snow"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <slide-y-up-transition>
      <component
        v-for="(girl, index) in girls"
        v-show="girl.hovered"
        v-bind:key="index"
        v-bind:is="girl.componentName"
      ></component>
    </slide-y-up-transition>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import { SlideYUpTransition } from "vue2-transitions";
import MyFirstComponent from "./colors/myycomponent";
import myOtherComponent from "./colors/myothercomponent";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {
    MyFirstComponent,
    myOtherComponent,
    SlideYUpTransition,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      componentNames: ["MyFirstComponent", "myOtherComponent"],
      girls: [
        {
          imgSrc:
            "https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/500px/983794168.jpg",
          hovered: false,
          hoverColor: "#337700",
          componentName: "MyFirstComponent",
        },
        {
          imgSrc:
            "https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/500px/983794168.jpg",
          hovered: false,
          hoverColor: "#123456",
          componentName: "myOtherComponent",
        },
      ],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    mouseOver: function (girl) {
      girl.hovered = true;
    },

    mouseout: function (girl) {
      girl.hovered = false;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is in your loop, transitions can only be used on a single element.

So do your loop this way to solve it.

```
<div v-for="(girl, index) in girls"  v-bind:key="index">
 <slide-y-up-transition>
      <component
        v-show="girl.hovered"       
        v-bind:is="girl.componentName"
      ></component>
    </slide-y-up-transition>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your full code has to be like this.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center">
      <div v-bind:key="index" v-for="(girl, index) in girls">
        <img
          style="width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 5px"
          @mouseover="mouseOver(girl, index)"
          @mouseout="mouseout(girl, index)"
          v-bind:src="girl.imgSrc"
          alt="Snow"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
   <div v-for="(girl, index) in girls" v-bind:key="index">
    <slide-y-up-transition >
      <component
        v-show="girl.hovered"
        v-bind:is="girl.componentName"
      ></component>
    </slide-y-up-transition>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { SlideYUpTransition } from "vue2-transitions";
import MyFirstComponent from "./colors/myycomponent";
import myOtherComponent from "./colors/myothercomponent";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {
    MyFirstComponent,
    myOtherComponent,
    SlideYUpTransition,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      componentNames: ["MyFirstComponent", "myOtherComponent"],
      girls: [
        {
          imgSrc:
            "https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/500px/983794168.jpg",
          hovered: false,
          hoverColor: "#337700",
          componentName: "MyFirstComponent",
        },
        {
          imgSrc:
            "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a9/76/af/a976af5c7bf3cc5b05a1b301334e0f68.jpg",
          hovered: false,
          hoverColor: "#123456",
          componentName: "myOtherComponent",
        },
      ],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    mouseOver: function (girl, index) {
      this.girls[index].hovered = true;
    },

    mouseout: function (girl, index) {
      this.girls[index].hovered = false;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```